# Trouble reading multinomial naive bayes notation

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, naive-bayes

$C_{MAP}$: most likely class (i.e., "maximum a posteriori")

$C_{NB}$: Naive Bayes

`x`: document `d` is represented as $x_n$ features or words

$c_j$: I think it's a class `j`

Source is here on page 27: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/naivebayes.pdf

---

Anyway,

$$ \begin{aligned}
C_{MAP} &= \mathop{\text{argmax}}_{c\in C} P(c|d)
\\&= \mathop{\text{argmax}}_{c \in C} \frac{P(d|c)P(c)}{P(d)} \qquad \text{(Bayes Rule)}
\\&= \mathop{\text{argmax}}_{c\in C} P(d|c)P(c)
\end{aligned}$$

Firstly, I thought Bayes Rule was just $\frac{P(d|c)}{P(d)}$, which is just conditional probability of the number of occurrences of {c & d}/d, so why is $P(c)$ multiplied by $P(d|c)$? And why is $c|d$ flipped to $d|c$?

Also, for multinomial naive bayes classifier, we have:

$$C_{NB} = \mathop{\text{argmax}}_{c \in C} P(c_j)\prod P(x | c). $$

I'm not sure how to read that equation... Is it saying Classifiers for N = the max probability of class j * PI of x in X * Probability of (x given c)?

If someone could help break down that notation that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAP = maximum a posteriori

Going down your equation line by line:

$$
\underset{ \boldsymbol{c \in C} }{\operatorname{argmax}} P( c | d )
$$

means there is a class (C) of things.  For each element of that class, calculate P( c | d )

an equivalent is

```
Type bestc = C[ 0 ];

for (Type c : C ){
  if (P( c | d ) > P( bestc | d )
    bestc = c;
}

return bestc
```

next line: bayes' theorem says you can flip conditioning, that is

$P(A | B ) = \frac{ P(B | A) \cdot P( A ) }{ P(B) }$

next line: you are selecting a c, and note that $P(d)$ is constant in c.  Thus you don't have to do the division.

The multinomial naive bayes classifier:
By basic probability theorems, you can break down a joint probability as follows (where $P(A,B,C,D) = $ the probability of A and B and C and D)
$$
\begin{align}
P(A,B,C,D) & = P(A) \cdot P(B,C,D|A) \\
& = P(A) \cdot P(B|A) \cdot P(C,D|A,B) \\
& = P(A) \cdot P(B|A) \cdot P(C|A,B) \cdot P(D \vert A,B,C)
\end{align}
$$

Then you apply the naive bayes assumption, that is, we assume
$$
P(D | A, B, C ) = P(D| class)
$$

That is, you have a bunch of observations, in typical machine learning notation, that look like
$ (y^{(i)}, \boldsymbol{x}^{(i)} )$
that is, we have $N$ observations indexed by $i$ where $y^{(i)}$ is a class and $\boldsymbol{x}^{(i)}$ is a vector of predictors.  In a typical use case, $i$ is a single email, $y^{(i)}$ is spam/not spam, and $\boldsymbol{x}^{(i)}$ is 1/0 counts for whether a vocabulary of words was present or not in that email.

Thus naive bayes says, as per the argmax in your first equation, we will train a classifier so that it will, for each example $y^{(new)}$, predict the probability that $y^{(new)}$ is spam and notspam, end up with two numbers, and classify as the class with the larger probability.  And our naive bayes assumption, for example:
$$
\begin{align}
P(y = \text{spam} | \boldsymbol{x} ) & = ... \\
& = \frac{ P( \boldsymbol{x} | y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P(y = \text{spam}) }{ P( \boldsymbol{x} ) } \\
& \text{ here I used bayes' theorem to flip conditioning} \\
& = P( \boldsymbol{x} | y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P(y = \text{spam}) \\
& \text{ because } P( \boldsymbol{x} ) \text{ doesn't depend on } c \\
& = P( x_{1},...,x_{m} | y = \text{spam}) \cdot P(y = \text{spam}) \\
& = P( x_{1} | y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P(x_{2:m} | x_{1}, y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P(y = \text{spam}) \\
& = P( x_{1} | y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P( x_{2} | x_{1}, y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P( x_{3:m}| y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P(y = \text{spam}) \\
& = \ldots \\
& = P( x_{1} | y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P( x_{2} | x_{1}, y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P( x_{3} | x_{1:2}, y = \text{spam} ) \cdot \ldots \cdot P( x_{m} | x_{1:m-1}, y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P(y = \text{spam} ) \\
& \text{and now I apply the naive bayes assumption} \\
& = P( x_{1} | y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P( x_{2} | y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P( x_{3} | y = \text{spam} ) \cdot \ldots \cdot P( x_{m} | y = \text{spam} ) \cdot P(y = \text{spam} ) \\
& = P(y=\text{spam}) \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{m} P( x_{i} | y = \text{spam} )
\end{align}
$$
where again, the naive bayes assumption is that $P( x_{k} | y = \text{spam}, x_{k+1:m} ) = P( x_{k} | y = \text{spam} )$
note that this is a *very* strong assumption, equivalent to saying that given an email from your friend that is not spam, the probability that the words sportscenter *and* basketball appear equals the probability that sportscenter appears times the probability basketball appears, which wildly misestimates that probability.